# Implementation of lexical analysis program in TEST language

Tags: c, lexical-analysis

This is the program I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char Scanin[300],Scanout[300];
    extern FILE *fin,*fout;

    printf("Please enter the source program file name (including the path): ");
    scanf("%s",Scanin);
    printf("Please enter the lexical analysis output file name (including the path):");
    scanf("%s",Scanout);
    if((fin=fopen(Scanin,"r"))==NULL)
             //Judge whether the input file name is correct
    {
        printf("\nError opening lexical analysis input file!\n");
        return 1;
                //Error in input file returned error code 1
    }

    if((fout=fopen(Scanout,"w"))==NULL)
        //Judge whether the output file name is correct
    {
        printf("\nError creating lexical analysis output file!\n");
        return 2;
                //Error in output file returned error code 2
    }
}
```

and this is the error I get:

Undefined reference to 'fout'
Undefined reference to 'fin'
error: 1d returned 1 exit status

This code was sent by my teacher and all she told me was to copy the code and give her an executable .exe file. And i am trying to ask help from her but she isn't responding to any of my messages, I am currently still having online classes.

Comment: This much code must be a small part of something much larger... Using the term `extern` means that `fin` and `fout` are defined somewhere else (not shown)... For the present, remove the word `extern` and the code should compile. (I'd look into getting a refund. This code presented here is "unhealthy" in its use of `scanf()`... Not a good start.) Look into whether or not there is a 'community' of other students taking the same course...

Comment: Thank you so much for this.... i can't really ask for a refund of anything as i am under a scholarship. But thank you so much for you help.

Comment: Good luck with the course. Although some SO questions can be quite "advanced", you might learn lots about C and programming merely by reading through the Q&A here. One issue often reported and corrected is "Why doesn't scanf() do what I want?"... Your teacher's code is deficient in this regard for the same reason others ask for help here. You can learn a lot from simply trying to understand what's been asked and answered.